# forwarding parameters indirectly deducible from function pointer type

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I want to have a function which accepts a pointer to a function and forwards all parameters as given by the function pointer type itself like this:

```
template < typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
auto Do1( RET(*ptr)(ARGS...), ARGS... args )
{
    (*ptr)(std::forward<ARGS>( args )...);
}

int main ()
{
    int i=4;

    Do1( &Ex1, i );
    Do1( &Ex2, i ); //fails!
    Do1( &Ex3, i+1 ); // fails
}
```

Functions to call are for both examples:

```
void Ex1( int i){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << i << std::endl; i=10;}
void Ex2( int& i){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << i << std::endl; i=20;}
void Ex3( int&& i){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << i << std::endl; i=30;}
```

It fails in case of `Ex2`and `Ex3` simply while it tries to deduce the type of the ARGS list two times and the result is different. The compiler complains with:

```
main.cpp:57:22: error: no matching function for call to 'Do1(void (*)(int&), int&)'
         Do1( &Ex2, i ); //fails!
                      ^   
main.cpp:33:10: note: candidate: 'template<class RET, class ... ARGS> auto Do1(RET (*)(ARGS ...), ARGS ...)'
     auto Do1( RET(*ptr)(ARGS...), ARGS... args )
          ^~~ 
main.cpp:33:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:57:22: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&' and 'int'
```

After that I tried to work around the problem with the following approach as I pick up the types by only one time deducing the ARGS list and forward once more to a intermediate lambda as follows:

```
template < typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
auto Do2( RET(*ptr)(ARGS...) )
{   
    return [ptr]( ARGS ... args )
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        (*ptr)(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...); 
    };
}   

int main ()
{   
    int i=4;

    Do1( &Ex1, i );
    Do1( &Ex2, i ); //fails!
    Do1( &Ex3, i+1 ); // fails

    Do2( &Ex1 )( i );
    std::cout << "now i: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Do2( &Ex2 )( i );
    std::cout << "now i: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Do2( &Ex3 )( i+1 );
    std::cout << "now i: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Q: Is there any way to repair the first approach in any case to get rid of the intermediate lambda here? And if not, is the solution with the intermediate lambda "well" designed, especially with all the "forwarding" things so that I did not create some copies or other unexpected behavior?

EDIT:
This is only a reduced example. It is not my intend to write a copy of `std::invoke`. So there is in my real world code a lot more to do inside the `Do` method itself.

It is important to get the needed types from the function pointer type as I have to perform some checks inside `Do` which are related to the types provided by the function pointer and *not* from the given additional parameters I provide from the user code to the `Do` method.

Comment: This looks to be logically equivalent to `std::invoke`. Just use `std::invoke`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It is only example code! In real world code there is a need to do lot more than invoking the given function by the pointer...

Comment: You could disable deduction on the function parameter pack by putting it in a non-deduced context and let the function pointer lead the deduction.

Comment: @Jans: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Klaus - Jarod42 has already provided it in his answer. The first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: Is there any way to repair the first approach in any case to get rid of the intermediate lambda here?

I suggest to accept the callable `ptr` simply as a type

```
template < typename F, typename ... ARGS >
auto Do1( F func, ARGS && ... args )
 {
    func(std::forward<ARGS>( args )...);
 }
```

This way your `Do1()` avoid completely the double-different deduction problem and works also with other types of callable (by example: with generic lambda that can't be simply converted to function pointer).

Otherwise you can intercept two variadic list of argument types

```
template < typename RET, typename ... AS1, typename ... AS2 >
auto Do1( RET(*ptr)(AS1...), AS2 && ... args )
 {
   (*ptr)(std::forward<AS2>( args )...);
 }
```

Comment: The first case did not fit to my needs as I have to perform some checks on the types given by the function signature presented via the function pointer. For your second solution: Is there missing `AS2&& ... args`?

Comment: @Klaus: and even `ARGS&&...` for first case too.

Comment: @Klaus - yes, sorry: `&&` forgotten in both cases (as observed by Jarod42); otherwise perfect forwarding doesn't works; corrected.

Comment: Since `Do1` is `auto` (even though all functions are `void` right now), perhaps this could be a future improvement (for the second solution): `auto Do1( RET(*ptr)(AS1...), AS2&&... args ) -> RET
 {
   return (*ptr)(std::forward<AS2>( args )...);
 }`

Comment: Just noticed the C++14 tag so the `-> RET` part can be skipped, Only `return` would need to be added.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: Is there any way to repair the first approach in any case to get rid of the intermediate lambda here?

You might change second args to be non deducible:

```
template <typename T>
struct non_deducible {
    using type = T;  
};
template <typename T>
using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;

template < typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
auto Do1( RET(*ptr)(ARGS...), non_deducible_t<ARGS>... args );
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9df462c2888bf6cf)

> is the solution with the intermediate lambda "well" designed, especially with all the "forwarding" things so that I did not create some copies or other unexpected behavior?

You do extra move constructs, so for `void Ex1(std::array<int, 5>)`, you copy twice the `std::array`.
Solution is forwarding reference:

```
template < typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
auto Do2( RET(*ptr)(ARGS...) )
{   
    return [ptr](auto&& ... args )
    -> decltype((*ptr)((decltype(args)(args))...))
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        (*ptr)((decltype(args)(args))...); 
    };
}
```

Simple alternatives are:

```
template < typename Ret, typename ... Ts, typename ... Args >
auto Do1( Ret(*ptr)(Ts...), Args&& ... args)
{
    (*ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or even

```
template < typename Func, typename ... Args >
auto Do1(Func f, Args&& ... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You might still have some `function_traits` to check `Func`.

Comment: sorry but... in your first solution... if `args` are "`non_deducible_t`" (and without `&&`) you don't loose perfect forwarding?

Comment: @max66: indeed, first solution has same issue than OP's lambda way with extra move construct. `&&` cannot be added, as non deducible, it would really be rvalue references (with reference collapsing) and not forwarding references.